# How can I totally remove TFS bindings from a solution?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

We have a large solution with many projects. Some of the projects were outsourced, and the vendor used TFS. When they commited into our SVN repo, some of the bindings are still hanging around.

When I open the sln, VS2008 says "The source control provider associated with the solution cannot be found, do you want to remove them". I hit yes, save and exit, and then next time it does it all again :)

So - anyone know how I cam get rid of any TFS bindings from the sln once and for all? Do I need to manually search the csproj files for any "scc" references and remove?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I completely remove TFS Bindings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358951/how-can-i-completely-remove-tfs-bindings)

Comment: I created a VSIX addon that removes TFS bindings and zips up a copy of your solution (also removes all unnecessary files). See http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb5d5d7d-f67e-4076-8fd0-23f36976deff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some PDA deployment projects(.vddproj) had some bindings hanging around. 
Just removed them manually :)

Comment: Awesome! Just to clarify - we manually edited the csproj files and vdproj files and removed all references to "Scc". But we also had some "vddproj" files hanging around that needed to be changed also - this did the trick and solved the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

The way to remove the bindings is to search the csproj files and remove it. There is a similar question on this topic already: See: [How to remove TFS source control bindings for a solution from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160495/how-to-remove-tfs-source-control-bindings-for-a-solution-from-the-command-line)

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to do this the hard way :) I saw the other post but found it a bit inconclusive, so thought I'd check.

Comment: It looks like there might be some automated tools described at the other one with a link to: http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/jake/archive/2008/05/21/2custom-nant-task-for-removing-tfs-bindings.aspx

I would start there.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a PowerShell script](http://purplestoat.com/blog/how-to-remove-tfs-source-control-info-from-a-vs-solution/) to remove the source control binding info.  It was ported from some C# and only tested on VS 2010 solutions.  The [original code](http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/jake/archive/2008/05/21/2custom-nant-task-for-removing-tfs-bindings.aspx) was written for VS 2005 and 2008 so you could probably add the relevant stuff back in.

Answer (score 1):

[Here you can find a tool](http://blog.instance-factory.com/?p=565) (including source code) to remove both SCC footprint from the solution and project files and the .vssscc and .vspscc files. In addition, it removes the output and other configurable directories.

Hth

Stefan