# How to disconnect solution from source control on TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a solution with solution folder and projects. 
Get the whole soure code from TFS in a local folder say c:\mycodes
Then copy the folder c:\mycode to another folder c:\lab

In c:\lab, remove all source control file *.vssscc, *.vspscc, then open the solution in c:\lab again.

Part of the project disconnect from TFS, but part of the projects in this solution still connect to TFS and some *.vssscc, *.vspscc files recreated when open the solution. Then unbind all project from server, those projects still have *.vspscc files auto generated.

I want to a clean copy of the source code with no source control. How to resolve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I totally remove TFS bindings from a solution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697195/how-can-i-totally-remove-tfs-bindings-from-a-solution)

Comment: This, by the way, is not a good SCM practics.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I completely remove TFS Bindings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358951/how-can-i-completely-remove-tfs-bindings)

Answer (score 59):

In Visual Studio, select the solution in the solution explorer, then go to the `File` menu.  Under the file menu, you'll see a `Source Control` menu.  Under that you'll see `Change Source Control`.

Select this, and in the dialog box that comes up, choose "unbind."

Your solution is no longer bound.

Comment: in Visual Studio 2010 in the dialog box that comes up, choose "Disconnect" .

Comment: This button does not appear unless you have any item within Solution Explorer selected.   If you have the Source Controller pane highlighted, for example,the button disappears.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2012 it's File > Source Control > Advanced > Change Source Control.

Comment: In VS2013 or VS2015, it is TEAM -> Disconnect from Team Foundation Server

Answer (score 15):

1. Delete *.vssscc, *.vspscc, files .
2. Open .sln file on notepad. Delete the code lines:

Code:

```
GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
        SccNumberOfProjects = 1
        SccEnterpriseProvider = JKHJ78900-10FA-6457-4535-645676465463}
        SccTeamFoundationServer = https://********.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection
        SccLocalPath0 = .
    EndGlobalSection
```

Comment: This is perfect when for example you have access to the source code but don't have access to the repository in source control.

Comment: This is it. All searching and pulling hair ends here. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

In VS-2013 from "Solution Explorer" select any solution. From FILE menu select **Source Control->Advance->Change Source control**. 
In the pop-up window you can finally click unbind button for each project of the solution. 
Took me a while to find from [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290675/how-to-disconnect-solution-from-source-control-on-tfs/3291423#3291423) by @Robaticus. Sorry, can't comment yet. 
[visual-studio-2013](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2013)

Answer (score 3):

I often need to take solutions or projects out of TFS source control to send to clients without and source control bindings left behind. I use a utility from CodePlex to acheive the job. PLease refer to my blog post "How to Permanently Remove TFS Source Control Bindings from Visual Studio Solutions (VS2012)" http://camerondwyer.wordpress.com/2012/11/07/how-to-permanently-remove-tfs-source-control-binding-from-visual-studio-solutions-vs2012/

Answer (score 1):

You must also edit the .sln file, because Visual Studio stores TFS Bindings mostly in this file, one line per project.

Err, wait. You'll still use some source control, right ?  Even if I'm no fan of TFS, dropping it for no source control would be a poor move.

Comment: There are still good reasons for doing this: e.g. stripping a project of bindings for transit offsite.

Answer (score 0):

**Visual Studio 2019**

Here are the steps to be taken to *"How to disconnect solution from source control on TFS"*.

Step 1)

[image]

Step 2)

[image]

Step3)

[image]

I had to do this, because I wanted to remove all information used by Azure Dev Ops and then post the project on GitHub.

Comment: This is for Git source control, and has nothing to do with TFS.