# Create File Structure

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Hello I've got a little problem while trying to create a new Project.

My aim is to get a total folder for sourc files, headers, external dependencies and ressource files auto generated.

Visual Studio does not create this folder for me.

I tried to activate and deactivate the plug in for controlling source code folders but it doesnt help.

At the beginning, when i ve created my first couple of projects it automaticallyy generated this folder. But now I do get nothing but my Project file without a source or a header folder

Thank You for every Help

Comment: what language? what source control?

Comment: c++, when you create a new file normlly it should generate a source folder a header folder and so on...

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating a new project there is a check box right above the OK button that says "Create a directory for this solution". Make sure this box is checked.

Comment: It doesnt work when i want to create a project, it asks to chosse a team foundation server computer, i dont know what to fill in there and break that, the checkbox is activatet

Comment: I have not worked with team foundation servers much but from what i've read you should be able to make a project local to your machine. Try selecting one of the projects and changing the source control to your local machine. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290675/how-to-disconnect-solution-from-source-control-on-tfs