# Visual Studio 2015 Nuget "There is no working folder mapping" Error

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2015

When adding the media services nuget package, VS 2015 is giving me errors about having no working folder mapping, then rolls back.

Here is an example of the message:

> There is no working folder mapping for C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\lib\net45.

When I open the same solution from VS 2013, it works as expected.

Does anyone know how to resolve the error is VS 2015, or perhaps why it doesn't work there but does work in VS 2013?

(In VS 2015, I opened the solution by browsing to the sln file locally - not by retrieving the solution from source control.)

Comment: I have the same issue myself - will update if I find a solution

Comment: I'm getting a similar issue with installing Build Web Compiler. However, it does add the package to the solution.

Comment: I just created a new project using source control and tried to upgrade nuget packages and having same issue

Comment: Same issue here! VS 2013 project opened in VS 2015 connected to TFS. Package manager is completely jacked and fails trying to do pretty much anything. Interestingly, I can add a new project and add packages with Nuget, but it barfs shortly afterward. New projects disconnected from source control seem to have the same problem.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue, plus several other issues with VS2015.

Comment: I also get many issue with VS2015.  I've switched back to VS2013 for many projects since things seem to work there.  Hopefully MS will release a fix for all of the VS2015 issues soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known bug: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1004 Use `Visual Studio 2013` for now. In the rush to get it out, `Microsoft` released a product that was not ready, even though technically this is a `NuGet` issue.

Answer (score 1):

Not a long term solution, but I unbound from TFS, added the packages I needed, then rebound.

Answer (score 0):

Try to unbound the solution and projects in TFS before updating the nuget packages.

To unbound try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290675/how-to-disconnect-solution-from-source-control-on-tfs)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to avoid the error if you unbound from TFS. To unbound, go to File->Source Control->Advance->Change Source Control. Select the project and click on the Unbound button\link at top.